# How do I get value from TimePicker(WPF) in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I downloaded MaterialDesignTheme from nuget in visualstudio.
http://materialdesigninxaml.net/

How do I get value form TimePicker?
I want to make this value stored in the string buffer.
How Can I implement MainWindow.xaml.cs?

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <materialDesign:TimePicker
              Is24Hours="True"
              x:Name="PresetTimePicker"
              SelectedTimeChanged="PresetTimePicker_SelectedTimeChanged" Height="26" Margin="141,94,369,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.025,5.923" />
        </Grid>
```

Comment: The best place to look is probably in the github project, which contains a demo application. Relevant code containing date/time pickers is [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Pickers.xaml) and [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Pickers.xaml.cs). If you manage to work it out from these, post your own answer below to help future users.

Comment: TimePicker has a Text property. Please try with that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TimePicker` control has a `SelectedTime` property that returns a `DateTime?`:

```
DateTime selectedTime = PresetTimePicker.SelectedTime.Value;
string formatted = selectedTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```